# jquery deep linking - how does it effect analytics?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, deep-linking

I am looking into using http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ , but I am wondering how it effects google analytics. Google analytics is a snippet of code at the bottom of pages. I would imagine deep linking would still look like activity on the initial page, not new pages.

Comment: Jared. Did you resolve this yet? If so can you post your answer?

Comment: bandhunt - no, I never came to a resolution, other than I noticed that the website that provides examples of jquery deep linking uses google analytics. I am just not familiar enough with analytics and deep linking to do an extensive test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see it will look to google analytics like navigating to a new page.

Just open e.g. http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/tabs/ and check the requests FF makes (e.g. with [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829)) and you will see that the google analytics fires a request for every tab you switch to.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Unfortunately, every tab says
 Referer: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/tabs/
At least that confirms that I am going to need some tricky coding...

Answer (score 0):

in it's current version 1.3 the jquery address plugin tries to do the ga tracking automatically, using the asynchronous ga tracking (see http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html). this is also mentioned in plugin's api docs at http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/#api-reference (look for $.address.tracker)

actually this new behaviour (i was using address' version 1.0 before) broke my custom tracking code on an ajax site - as it isn't configurable, i had to downgrade to 1.0.

Answer (score -3):

As long as the page, and the analytics code is being loaded, it will still count as a hit on the page. I don't think there would be any negative impacts of using this plug in.