# jquery address google analytics

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-analytics, jquery-address

I'm using the popular jquery address with an ajax app. I want google analytics to record path hash changes, as those are the equivalent of new pages for me.

The address documentation mentions GA, but I don't understand how to use it?

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/

This also mentions the feature but doesn't explain how to do tracking:
[jquery deep linking - how does it effect analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907881/jquery-deep-linking-how-does-it-effect-analytics)

Do I still reference the google urchin js on my html page? Below or after address? Is the function the function that causes the page change? Can I put $.address.change() in it?

Comment: Here's another question that I think you'll find of interest to what you are doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin should do the tracking automatically as long as you have included one the Google Analytics code. It supports the all the variants of the code (urchin, pageTracker, async) but there are two important things:

1. The GA code should be included
   before the plugin. This is needed so
   that the plugin can detect the
   tracking script.
2. The last line of the tracking code
   where the "" is tracked should be
   removed. The plugin will invoke this
   automatically and will use a proper
   value if the website is entered
   using a deep link.

All the jQuery Address samples on asual.com use this tracking capability and you can use their source as a reference.

Comment: Looking at the code of jquery.address, the GA code does not necessarily need to load before jquery.address loads. When an address change occurs, jquery.address internally fires ._track(), which in turn calls _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'... if present; in other words, until GA loads, this will have no effect. As soon as GA has loaded, jquery.address will start making use of it. If both are loading asynchronously, you may need to explicitly track the initial pageload like _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', decodeURI($.address.value())]);